# Catching async exception in main thread

Tags: c#, sql, asynchronous, async-await

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestAsync
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string conn = "Data Source=UNREACHABLESERVER;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                TestConnection();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught in main");
            }
        }

        private static async void TestConnection()
        {
            bool connected = false;

            using (var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {
                tokenSource.CancelAfter(2000);

                try
                {
                    await connection.OpenAsync(tokenSource.Token);
                    connected = true;
                }
                catch(TaskCanceledException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Caught timeout");
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.Write("Caught in function");
                }

                if (connected)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect...");
                    throw(new Exception("hi"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Caught timeout
Failed to connect...
```

But then my program terminates with an unhandled exception. Instead, I'm wanting my program to have the thrown exception handled in the main thread and print out `Caught in main`. How can I make that work?

**EDIT**

Here's my updated code that works the way I want:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestAsync
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string conn = "Data Source=UNREACHABLESERVER;Initial Catalog=MyFiles;Integrated Security=True";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                TestConnection().Wait();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught in main");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task TestConnection()
        {
            using (var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {
                tokenSource.CancelAfter(2000);
                await connection.OpenAsync(tokenSource.Token);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible. Your call to `TestConnection()` will return (and thus execution on the main thread will continue) once your first `await` is encountered. Your `catch` blocks and throwing the exception will execute on another thread and go unobserved by the main thread.

This one just one reason why `async void` should be avoided. If you need to write an `async void` function, it *must* be completely self-contained (including error handling logic). You would be much better off writing an `async Task` function. The simplest approach would be to modify your call in the `Main` method to this:

```
TestConnection().Wait()
```

This will, of course, cause the main thread to block while executing the function (you'll also have to change the signature to `async Task` before this will compile).

Comment: Correct except for the second sentence. `async` methods always start synchronously. However, even if an exception is thrown during the synchronous portion, it will not be propagated to the caller.

Comment: @StephenCleary: True, not sure what I was thinking. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: I feel that your edit did not adequately address @Stephen's concern. In particular, your answer still implies that the exception _always_ happens in another thread. This isn't the case. In particular, even if the `await` completes synchronously, such that the continuation is executed in the current thread, the exception will _still_ not be observed by the caller. This is by design semantics of `async` method.